# How to sync Stripe subscription in Firestore when using Payment Links?

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments, webhooks, subscription, firebase-extensions

I've a web app (React) which uses Firebase as the backend. I'm integrating Stripe for subscriptions to my app. To sync a user's subscription details to Firestore, I installed this [Run Payments with Stripe extension](https://extensions.dev/extensions/stripe/firestore-stripe-payments) on Firebase. The extension says the following on how to create a subscription.

> To subscribe the user to a specific pricing plan, create a new doc in the `checkout_sessions` collection for the user.

However, I'm trying to use Payment Links in my web app (which gives me greater flexibility and lesser maintainence going forward). I created a Payment Link and completed a purchase in Test Mode. But the user's subscription related data is not synced in Firestore.

I looked into the logs of the `ext-firestore-stripe-payments-handleWebhookEvents` function and found the following error.

> ❗️[Error]: Webhook handler for  Stripe event [evt_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] of type [customer.subscription.created] failed: User not found!

Now, I would like to know if it is possible to use Payment Links with this firebase extension? If yes, how can I sync the user id between Firebase and Payment Link, so that the user details are updated in Firestore and auth claims are set as described.

*PS: The failed event doesn't show up in Stripe dashboard. Only successful webhook events are list item even though there is a separate tab for failed events.*

Comment: I don't know much about firebase, but Payment Links can't be associated with a specific Customer object in Stripe. Each purchase with a Payment Link creates a new Customer. This might be the reason. Instead, you can look at using Stripe Checkout, which is also a hosted checkout experience, but offers a greater flexibility, incl. being able to attach an existing Customer: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. That could be a reason.

Comment: @vanya Not seeing where we're able to attach an existing customer using Stripe Checkout. Can you help with finding that specific information?

Comment: @tazboy https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer

Comment: Hello @imthath! I am also interested in this matter, how did you tackle the problem?

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible to associate user identifiers automatically with Payment Links. Hence it is not possible. You have to use Stripe Connect to sync payments with Firebase using the extension.

One workaround you can try is have a custom webhook which users email id from the payment link and then looks through the users collection for the email id and updates accordingly.